# C и неожиданное поведение

Tags: c

Знакомлюсь понемногу с си, закономерно попадаю в ситуации, которые вызывают острый wtf. Есть программа, она не работает, но дело не в этом, а в волшебной строчке:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "include/types.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    int64_t i = 0x01234567abcdef8;
    int32_t *s = serialize_int64(i);
    //printf("1: %d, 2: %d\n", s[0], s[1]); волшебная строчка
    int64_t ds = deserialize_int64(s);
    printf("source value:    %ld\n", i);
    printf("converted value: %ld\n", ds);
    return 0;
}
```

Если ее раскомментировать, то с каждым вызовом программа начнет генерировать новые значения. Почему это происходит?

Содержимое остальных файлов:

include/types.h

```
#pragma once
#include <stdint.h>
int32_t * serialize_int64(int64_t _int64);
int64_t deserialize_int64(int32_t int32_array[]);
```

src/types.c

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int32_t * serialize_int64(int64_t _int64)
{
    int32_t out[2];
    out[0] = _int64 >> 32;
    out[1] = _int64 & 0xFFFFFFFF;
    return out;
}
int64_t deserialize_int64(int32_t int32_array[])
{
    return int32_array[0] << 32 | int32_array[1];
}
```

Для дочитавших до сюда есть бонус-вопрос, за который я, кажется, получу за невнимательность к предмету. Есть ли возможность одной строкой создать и вернуть массив?

Comment: @Fike, в одну строчку, даже без проверки на успех выделения памяти, неказисто выглядит, а вот в 4 

    static inline int32_t *serialize_int64 (uint64_t x) { 
      void *v = malloc(sizeof(x)); 
      return v ? memcpy(v, &x, sizeof(x)) : 0; 
    }

Ваша задачка вполне решается.

Ну, а эффект с возвращением памяти в стеке вызываемой функции Вам уже обрисовали.

--

Впрочем, если выделение памяти под массив предоставить вызывающей функции, то: 

    static inline int32_t *foo (uint64_t x, uint32_t serialize[]) { 
      return memcpy(serialize, &x, sizeof(x)); 
    }

можете записать и одной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `serialize_int64` возвращает указатель на значения `out` размещенные на стеке (иными словами указатель на локальную переменную). Функция `printf`, после выхода из `serialize_int64`, использует ровно ту же самую память на стеке под свои локальные переменные, и может оставлять там произвольный мусор. Этот самый мусор и используется затем в `deserialize_int64`.

Comment: И от этого не избавиться до тех пор, пока не создавать массив извне, так?

Comment: Не избавиться от чего?

Comment: От использования памяти, в которой лежит созданный внутри функции массив

Comment: Для того, чтобы не использовать память, в которой лежит созданный внутри функции массив, нужно просто не использовать эту память.

Для того, чтобы избежать непреднамеренного обращения по указателю к памяти выделенной под стек функций, можно использовать другие области памяти (например, создавать массивы извне, что бы это не значило).